# How to get Last Run Result from TFS Backup plan

Tags: tfs

I'm new to TFS admin panel.

my question is

> How to get Last run result of Scheduled task with in Back up plan ?

[image: TFS backup plan]

I couldn't find the log path where this wizard reading status ? Could some one help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can find it in TFS logs.

Open Administrator Console. Click **Logs** in the left Side navigation bar, click **Open Logs Folder** on the right.The  default path(C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Server Configuration\Logs). Search the log you need.

For example:
The Back Up log format is **TFS_Scheduled_Backups_Date(ex. 1026)_xxxxx**.log